# Create the title sliding when hover mouse using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have h2 tag and have width just 100px but the text content inside h2 tag is more than 100px, i want to show text content appear just in one line. I want to make it like on brazzers.com, When user hover the mouse on title of post, the long title of post will be sliding to show all. Is there a way to create it using jquery? Sorry about my newbie question

Comment: +1 for the brazzers.com example :)

Comment: I imagine some users are not in a position where they are comfortable checking the example on brazzers.com. It would probably help if you could give another source to check what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QKstB/2/

This is a script:

```
var textWidth = $('h1 nobr').outerWidth(),
    totalWidth = $('h1').outerWidth(),
    diff = totalWidth - textWidth;

$('h1').hover( function() {
    $('h1 nobr').animate({ 'margin-left': diff }, 5000, function() { 
        $(this).css('margin-left', 0)
    });
}, function() { 
    $('h1 nobr').stop(true, true);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a one exactly example i want. But when i hover the title it didn't come back to normal position, is there another way to make the title back to normal again after user leave hover the title?

Comment: @JhonnyJr. Fixed, please check a new link. You can play with 2 hover functions and animate params to get effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is something you can just do with CSS and hover behaviors

```
#test {
    width:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#test:hover
{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYEfs

*Also, maybe a nsfw warning on the reference link?*

Answer (score 0):

I would create a div with overflow: hidden and inside this div would be the h2 tag with postion set to relative or absolute (depends on your structure and intended behaviour). As soon as the mouse is over the div I would use http://api.jquery.com/animate/ to animate the css "left" property to a negative value.

P.S: Did not check the example, due to being on work ...